# Strange behaviour of gcc in Debian

Tags: c, linux, gcc, debian

```
char * stft (const char *fmt, ...) {

    va_list items;
    char *out;
    int magic = 0; // <-- here magic?

    va_start (items, fmt);
    vsprintf (out, fmt, items);
    va_end (items);

    return out;

}
```

Use like:

```
char *str = stft ("%s-%s %s", a, b, c);
```

This is working solution?
if delete unused "magic" variable - I have Segmentation fault after return string.
What doing wrong?

$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5

$ uname -a
Linux deep-station (squeeze) 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Fri May 10 08:33:48 UTC 2013 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: unrelated to the question, but shouldn't there be something to initialize `out`?

Comment: @guest: not unrelated to the question -- the problem is precisely that `out` is not initialized so crashes occur.

Comment: nice sleuthing. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write to an uninitialized pointer `out`.  That's why you crash.  It is badly undefined behaviour.  The magic is coincidental; it does not make the behaviour any better defined.

It is probably best to use [`vsnprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vsnprintf.html):

```
char *out = malloc(256);
...
vsnprintf(out, 256, fmt, items);
...
return out;
```

Or something similar.

You can improve this.  For example:

```
char *stft(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list items;

    va_start(items, fmt);
    int length = vsnprintf(0, 0, fmt, items);
    va_end(items);
    char *out = malloc(length+1);
    if (out != 0)
    {
        va_start(items, fmt);
        vsnprintf(out, length+1, fmt, items);
        va_end(items);
    }

    return out;
}
```

Make sure you free the allocated memory in the calling code.

Comment: >>> Make sure you free the allocated memory in the calling code.
For unuse free() I wanted solutions and found strange behavior

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.  If you don't want the function to allocate memory, then you have two choices.  The better choice is to pass in a buffer (`char *buffer`) and its length (`size_t buflen`), and then use these: `vsnprintf(buffer, buflen, fmt, items)`.  The worse choice is `static char buffer[256];` in the function and `vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fmt, items);`.  This has concurrency issues, and means you can't call the function twice and keep both formatted strings without explicit copying.  Both of these may have a buffer that's too short.

Comment: Thanks for solution! Now I use global buffer only for single call of stft() and with one call reallocated buffer length for current stft() context. Thanks much!